# I am trying to reference a merged cell on one worksheet and have it copy over into the next sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So basically my workbook has four individual sheets. I want to reference the text in the sheet labeled **Overall Assessment** and it is E81:L86 (merged cells). I want to put it in my sheet labeled **Summary** in merged cell F15:K15. What formula should I use? ='Overall Assessment'!E81:L86 is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In excel, merged cells are referred to as the address of the top left-most cell that was merged.

Say you merge `A2:A8` - to reference this cell just use `A2`

Similarly Merged `A2:C8` would be `A2`

Answer (score 0):

by just typing "=" then selecting the merged cell on another sheet you will get something like this: ='Service Quote'!A22:F22

as indicated above all you need to do is edit the formula to this ='Service Quote'!A22

ie remove the cell range part of the formula.